# User imports with cron job

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have a drupal website where i wonna import user settings with a CSV ( Comma separate file ) file. I can do that with the user imports module. But this is manually. You need to choose a csv file and can then change some settings,... to import that file. That is no problem.

Now i wonna do that automaticly ( cron ? ). I have read that it could be done with the same user imports module. But i can't get it working. Somebody that can help me starting, to do the following.

So that he gonna see to an ftp location if there is a new csv file.
The he gonna do the import.

He must do changes for users that already exists an add new users if they doesn't exists. And for users that where deleted from the file , the user should set to inactive.

And after this, there should be a report with al the changes that are made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice. But i am rewriting the module into a new module. With everything i need. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the feeds module. You can easily set it up to import on a schedule and can specify a local folder to look for new files. You can also set it up to access a remote url for the file, but only through http not ftp. We do a similar import and have a bash script that transfers the file to a local folder and then use feeds to import the resulting file.